# Não consigo fazer Autenticação Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

já estou há algum tempo tentando fazer uma autenticação e não consigo, sou um iniciante no ramo, quem se dispor a me ajudar saiba que estará praticamente salvando minha vida, pois já pensei em desistir várias vezes de trabalhar com isso.

Estou chamando um método do controller pelo formulário de login./

View:

```
{{Form::open(array('action' => 'UsuarioController@Login', 'method' => 'POST'))}}
```

No controller estou setando uma variável e procurando no banco se existe o login digitado conforme o campo login da tabela, depois faço a verificação se o login e senha retorna verdadeiro para redirecionar a view desejada, se não, retorna a view de login. /

Controller:

```
class UsuarioController extends Controller
{
    public function Login(Request $request)
    {
        $usuario = UsuarioEsic::where('login','=',$request->get('login'))->first();

        if ($usuario && $usuario->senha)      {

            Auth::login($usuario);

            return view('e_sic.usuario.esic_content');   

        } else { 
           return view('e_sic.inicio.esic_conteudo'); 
        }

    }
}
```

Model:

```
    class UsuarioEsic extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'usuario_esic';
    public $timestamps = false;
    public static $snakeAttributes = false;
    protected $dates = ['dataNasc'];
}
```

Obs: Não entendi bem o lance das rotas usando o auth, achei que estava fazendo certo conforme os tutoriais que vi.

Rota:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::auth();
    Route::post('/Login', 'UsuarioController@Login');
});
```

Auth.php:

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => Portal\Entity\Local\UsuarioEsic::class,
        ],
```

AuthController:

```
protected $redirectTo = 'Esic/Conteudo';
```

Toda vez que eu tento logar ele diz que a página não foi encontrada e me redireciona para o url eu tendo ou não digitado qualquer coisa no formulário de login.

Eu já pesquisei vários tópicos em diversos fóruns, já vi videos e li tutoriais a respeito e mesmo assim não consigo ter progresso nisso, sei o quanto tenho dificuldade de aprender as coisas, mas estou aqui pedindo encarecidamente que alguém de bom coração perca um pouco do seu tempo me ensinando/explicando como eu faço isso funcionar perfeitamente, por favor !
Grato desde já.

Obs: Qualquer dúvida sobre o código estou disposto a passar qualquer informação !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente o que pude perceber no seu código tem erros até de segurança na parte de autenticação, porque:

É feito um `select` na base e compara ***verdadeiro* && *verdadeiro*** nessa linha (`if ($usuario && $usuario->senha)` e manda autenticar sem verificar, isso é falha de segurança todos vão logar no seu site e ai já viu o que acontecer.

**Uma autenticação básica seria com um método assim:**

```
public function auth(Request $request)
{

    $values = $request->values();

    if (Auth::attempt($values, false))
    {    
        return redirect()->intended('admin/');
    }

    return 'error';

}
```

Nesse `$request` vem duas **informações**: `email` e `password` e nesse método do `Auth::attempt` ele verifica se o usuário existe, se sim, autentica o usuário dando permissão a utiliza a área restritiva, se não dá uma mensagem de **"error"** que nesse momento você pode trabalhar as informações de *Login inválido* e assim por diante.

---

Na parte de rotas funciona assim: (depende muito da lógica empregada)

***Exemplo:*** `Route Login`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function ()
{
 Route::get('/admin/login', ['as'=>'admin.login','uses'=>'LoginController@index']);
 Route::post('/admin/auth', ['as'=>'admin.auth','uses'=>'LoginController@auth']);
});
```

***Exemplo:*** `Route que vai utilizar a autenticação`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth'], 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function ()
{
    //CREDIT
    Route::get('/admin/credit', ['as' => 'credit', 'uses' => 'CreditController@index']);
    ...
});
```

Ou seja, na rotas do **login** não pode ter `auth` que verifica se algum usuário está logado, já nas outras rotas que precisam de autenticação foi adicionado `auth`

---

Configure também no **Middleware** `Authenticate` (***pasta*** `app\Http\Middleware`)

```
class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

o seu redirecionamento de autenticação: `return redirect()->guest('admin/login');`, no meu caso é **admin/login**.

Comment: Amigo, muito obrigado por se dispor a me ajudar, tenho algumas dúvidas no seu exemplo acima, no $request você me disse que ele tem duas informações, que no caso é email e password, como eu mudaria para os campos desejados por mim? Por exemplo: Login e Senha .

Comment: Cara, acho que essa área não é pra mim, mesmo que tantos tutoriais e exemplos eu não consigo fazer uma simples autenticação. Complicado !

Comment: Em um form coloque duas caixas de texto com os referidos nome(email e password)

Comment: Mas eu quero ter total controle do que to fazendo, é importante saber como se faz manualmente as coisas ao invez de simplesmente usar o sistema totalmente pronto, eu poderia da o 'php artisan make:auth' e editar tudo que fosse viável, no entanto preciso aprender o que to fazendo, só que ta um pouco complicado, sou leigo no assunto.

Comment: @LincolnBinda eu entendo sua preocupação em aprender e é válida, mas, aqui no stackoverflow ficaria dificil acredito eu ensinar um passo a passo, desculpas, mas, acho que o site é para tirar dúvidas imediatas dentro de contextos. (Se não estiver engando) Tem cursos de Laravel você poderia entrar nesse grupo que é bem ativo: http://laravel-br.slack.com/ se increva - lá que o pessoal pode te ajudar principalmente em cursos.

Comment: Ótimo João, obrigado pela ajuda cara. 

Obs: Eu até tenho uma certa noção, já fiz algumas coisas e aprendi bastante nesse tempo de estudo, sem falar na ajuda que tive aqui no fórum, mas em particular, no caso da autenticação estou me enrolando bastantes, não entrou na minha cabeça mesmo, enfim, irei me empenhar mais, obrigado novamente.